# Autorole using role defined by user

Tags: discord.js

i'm trying to do an Autorole command, then it gives the role the user wants to every new members.

my code :
main.js :

```
const mentionedRole = require("./cmds/autorole")  
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {

member.roles.add(mentionedRole);
})
```

autorole command :

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {



    const mentionedRole = message.mentions.roles.first();
  
    if (!mentionedRole) return message.channel.send(`I cannot to use the role: ${mentionedRole}`);
  
    message.channel.send(`Autorole successfully added (${mentionedRole}).`);
  }
```

the error it gives :

```
Supplied roles is not an Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes.
```

Answer (score 0):

To give a role by mention `message.mentions.roles.first()` you need to `@testRole`
So I'd recommend doing it like this:

```
   const mentionedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === args.slice(1).join(" "));
  
    if (!mentionedRole) return message.channel.send(`I cannot to use the role: ${mentionedRole}`);
  
    message.channel.send(`Autorole successfully added (${mentionedRole}).`);
```

Now when it should look like this:
ex. ?autorole testRole
not ?autorole @testRole

Comment: Not the error, it doesn't matter either way, they both result in a Role class